# Material-UI Autocomplete store only a single property of an object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I'm trying to use [Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/)
 but I need to make the value store only the a specifc property and not a full object.

e.g. 
This case is the property `Value`, but it can be any.

```
const options = [
  { Value: 1, label: "Option 1", anyOtherProp: 123 },
  { Value: 2, label: "Option 2", anyOtherProp: 456 },
  { Value: 3, label: "Option 3", anyOtherProp: 789 }
];

export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  const valueKey = "Value"; // this should be any key

  const handleChange = (e, value) => {
    // what to do here?
    setValue(value[valueKey]);
  };    

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Autocomplete
        options={options}
        onChange={handleChange}
        value={value}
        getOptionLabel={option => option.label}
        renderInput={props => <TextField {...props} fullWidth />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I do this, the input is empty and shows nothing.

I need the value to be only one property of the object and not the full option's object.

Here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/peaceful-northcutt-b4ks7) that shows the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for `value` and call the `setValue`. also replace `value` props on `CustomAutocomplete` to `defaultValue`, all will work fine.
Check the fiddle [Fiddle Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-hypatia-8f614?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
export default function App() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  const valueKey = "Value"; // this should be any key

  const handleChange = (e, value) => {
    // what to do here?
    if(value) setValue(value[valueKey]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CustomAutocomplete
        onChange={handleChange}
        defaultValue={value}
        options={options}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: In your fiddle,  you pass `defaultValue` to `CustomAutocomplete` but it doesn't pass to `Autocomplete`. So in your case, you don't even need to pass `value` to the component?

Comment: Need to update the same in `Autocomplete` also. it can be value in `CustomAutocomplete` but it needs to be `defaultValue` in `Autocomplete` component. Nice catch.

Comment: This gives me a problem when using it inside a `.map` when removing a item from the list. Do your know how to solve it?

Comment: @Vencovsky can you give more details, I haven't worked with material UI. Providing a fiddle will be more helpful

Comment: Please check this [gist](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-dust-1c8t2). The values are already there, but the input is empty (problem here) and also, if you add some fields with some value and then delete the first field, the input shows wrong data.

Comment: @Vencovsky the way you implemented listing is wrong, thats why wrong data showing all the time.

Comment: What is wrong? Could you please tell me? I can't see it

Comment: @Vencovsky the way you implemented is wrong, I dont have much time now, but definitely will create a fiddle on this and share with you.

Comment: Please explain better, waiting for your response, thanks

Comment: hi, at last found the bug, its in `values.map((value, index) => (
          <div key={index}>
            <CustomAutocomplete ...... >` the `key` attribute. since the index remains same even after removing an item form the `values` array, the `autocomplete` option removed the last item. you can add some unique value in place of `key` and check. If you find any difficulty,  I will help. Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: I have added unique `key` value attribute based on the field value. It still doesn't work

Comment: @Vencovsky can you share the fiddle link, I checked it and was working good.

Comment: @Vencovsky please check the this fiddle, ping me if the problem is not resolved. https://codesandbox.io/s/sharp-chebyshev-vcbmt?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark